# Exposing a C symbol containing a zero terminated array of function pointers from Rust to C

Tags: rust, ffi

I have the following C code which is compiled as a `.so`:

```
void (*vlog_startup_routines[])() = {
    hello_register,
    0
};
```

In Rust, I can declare functions with `#[no_mangle]`. How would I expose a symbol called `vlog_startup_routines` which is an array containing function pointers and also zero terminated?

Comment: Interesting. An array is nothing more than a pointer, and being 0 terminated is a run-time property. However I am not sure how to pass pointer to functions across the FFI boundary; have you checked the existing Rust documentation?

Comment: @MatthieuM. and the array pointer basically doesn't exist here; `(void *)hello_register == (void *)vlog_startup_routines`, right?

Comment: I'd suggest working on your wording when asking questions. Providing C code makes it look like you *want to call that code*. It would have been better to provide C code that uses an `extern` to highlight that you want to implement that symbol in Rust. Additionally, when you have a library, there's nothing to drive the program, so nothing would get called. A C executable would better express the problem.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Note quite; `*hello_register == vlog_startup_routines`, as the array contains a pointer to the function, not the function itself, which matters if one wishes to have multiple functions I suppose. So in Rust, `hello_register` will be something like `*const fn()` I suppose, allowing arithmetic.

Comment: @MatthieuM. perhaps you can help me figure out why [my code says they are the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40567119/how-do-i-access-an-array-of-function-pointers-declared-in-c-from-rust)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a `static` item whose type is an array. When defining a `static` item, unfortunately, we need to specify the size of that array (as of Rust 1.13.0).

Function pointers in Rust are not considered unsafe to call (unless you have an `unsafe fn`). However, a null pointer would not be safe to call, so Rust doesn't allow creating a null function pointer. But there's a trick: when `T` is a pointer (whichever kind of pointer, including fat pointers and function pointers), [`Option<T>` has the same size as `T`<sup>1</sup>, and `None` is simply represented as a null pointer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html#the-nullable-pointer-optimization). Thus, we can define an array of `Option<fn()>` values to get the desired result.

<sup>1</sup> For other types, `Option<T>` would be larger than `T` to store the discriminant.

```
#[no_mangle]
#[allow(non_upper_case_globals)]
pub static vlog_startup_routines: [Option<fn()>; 2] = [
    Some(hello_register),
    None
];
```

If having to specify the array size annoys you, then you can use a macro that computes it for you. As a bonus, this macro adds the trailing `None` and wraps each function in `Some`.

```
macro_rules! one_for {
    ($_x:tt) => (1)
}

macro_rules! vlog_startup_routines {
    ($($func:expr,)*) => {
        #[no_mangle]
        #[allow(non_upper_case_globals)]
        pub static vlog_startup_routines: [Option<fn()>; $(one_for!($func) +)* 1] = [
            $(Some($func),)*
            None
        ];
    }
}

vlog_startup_routines! {
    hello_register,
}
```

*Note: the `one_for` macro exists because we need to reference one of the parameter symbols in a repeating pattern (you can have multiple distinct repetitions, so the compiler needs to know which one you're referring to) but we don't care about its value.*

Comment: `None`; of course! I couldn't figure out how to make a `NULL` with the appropriate type. Sigh.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about option but i figured there could be a better alternative since only the last element should be 0. I guess there isn't yet.