# How do I access a zero-terminated array of function pointers declared in C from Rust?

Tags: rust, function-pointers, ffi

I have the following C code with a zero-terminated array of function pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void hello_register(void) {
  printf("hello_register called\n");
}

void (*vlog_startup_routines[])() = {
    hello_register,
    0
};
```

This code is compiled and linked to my Rust program using a Cargo build script. How can I call each of the function pointers in the array from Rust?

Comment: There's a small possibility I read another question completely backwards and wanted to post the answer I worked on anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A combination of the previous two answers looks nicer:

```
extern crate libc;

type VlogStartupRoutine = Option<extern "C" fn()>;

extern "C" {
    // This array is NULL-terminated; set the length to zero to
    // prevent any uncontrolled access.
    static vlog_startup_routines: [VlogStartupRoutine; 0];
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let routines = vlog_startup_routines.as_ptr();

        for i in 0.. {
            match *routines.offset(i) {
                Some(routine) => {
                    println!("Calling startup routine #{}", i);
                    routine();
                }
                None => break,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

The symbol `vlog_startup_routines` is not a pointer to a function pointer, it's an array of function pointers. When you use the name `vlog_startup_routines` in C code, the array lvalue is coerced to a pointer. That doesn't mean that the variable stores a pointer!

To most closely express this in Rust, we can define `vlog_startup_routines` as an array. The problem is that we don't know how many elements are in the array because it's NULL-terminated. To prevent any accidental misuse, we set the length to zero and only access elements though offsets of the raw pointer.

We use `Option<extern "C" fn()>` for the nullable function pointer as described in the [FFI chapter of *The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html#the-nullable-pointer-optimization).

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that `vlog_startup_routines` is not a pointer.  If you declare it as a pointer; it is an array.  The symbol resolves to the address of the first item of the array.  In C, if you have:

```
int i = 7;
int a[1] = { 8 };
int *p = &i;
```

then at the linker level, the symbol `i` is the address of the location containing the value 7, `a` is *also* the address of a location containing an integer value (8), and `p` is the address of a location containing a pointer to an integer.  Another way of saying it is that the linker symbol is always the address of the variable.

If you declare it as:

```
// Or whatever argument types
type VlogStartupRoutine = extern "C" fn();

extern "C" {
    static vlog_startup_routines: VlogStartupRoutine;
}
```

you're saying that `vlog_startup_routines` is a variable containing a function pointer, more like the C `void *vlog_startup_routines`.

```
unsafe {
    println!("{:p}", vlog_startup_routines);
    println!("{:p}", hello_register as *const ());
}
```

it's dereferencing taking the value stored at the address `vlog_startup_routines`, which is indeed the first pointer.

The correct (nearly) code is:

```
type VlogStartupRoutine = Option<extern "C" fn()>;

#[link(name = "funcref")]
extern "C" {
    static vlog_startup_routines: [VlogStartupRoutine;10];
    fn hello_register();
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        println!("{:p}", vlog_startup_routines.as_ptr());
        println!("{:p}", hello_register as *const ());
    }
    unsafe {
        let routine = vlog_startup_routines[0].unwrap();
        println!("Calling startup");
        routine();
        assert!(vlog_startup_routines[1].is_none());
    }
}
```

Note that I use `Option<extern "C" fn()>` for the nullable function pointer as [described here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html#the-nullable-pointer-optimization).

This outputs, for me:

```
0x7efc27d37030
0x7efc27b366f0
Calling startup
hello_register called
```

The reason I say "nearly" is that I'm not sure how to say it's an unknown-sized array.  :-)

Comment: The only work-around I have to offer for the unknown size is to give it a size of `1` (because that's the minimum size), and then ignore it when looping... but I am not sure whether the compiler can do weird optimizations on this.

Comment: Or zero as in @Shepmaster's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a *single* function pointer easily enough:

```
extern crate libc;

// Or whatever argument types
type VlogStartupRoutine = extern "C" fn();

extern "C" {
    static vlog_startup_routines: VlogStartupRoutine;
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let routine = vlog_startup_routines;
        println!("Calling startup");
        routine();
    }
}
```

However, note that we and the C compiler are doing some trickery here: the array and the first element of the array have the same value:

```
extern "C" {
    static vlog_startup_routines: VlogStartupRoutine;
    fn hello_register();
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        println!("{:p}", vlog_startup_routines);
        println!("{:p}", hello_register as *const ());
    }
}
```

```
0x1029bf750
0x1029bf750
```

To work around this, we grab a reference to the initial function and then use that to iterate though each of the function pointers. I've renamed `vlog_startup_routines` just to prevent any accidental misuse of it.

```
extern crate libc;

// Or whatever appropriate argument types
type VlogStartupRoutine = extern "C" fn();

extern "C" {
    #[link_name = "vlog_startup_routines"]
    static INITIAL_VLOG_STARTUP_ROUTINE: VlogStartupRoutine;
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let startup_routines: *const VlogStartupRoutine = &INITIAL_VLOG_STARTUP_ROUTINE;

        for i in 0.. {
            let routine = *startup_routines.offset(i);

            let routine_as_ptr = routine as *const ();
            if routine_as_ptr.is_null() { break }

            println!("Calling startup routine #{}", i);
            routine();
        }
    }
}
```

This all feels pretty janky, so I wouldn't be surprised if there were a better solution available, but this does work.

Comment: What's janky about it? It looks exactly like I would expect! :-)

Comment: @BurntSushi5 mostly around having to take the reference. I spent so much time thinking I did my "normal" function pointer mistake, which is having too many layers of references. It took me a while to realize I didn't have *enough*.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you're getting the same address for the table and function.  Are you being fooled by an auto-deref in println!()?  I compiled your C code with `gcc -fPIC -shared funcref.c -o funcref.so`, and looking at the .so with `objdump -t` has the two at different addresses, and in different sections.

Comment: @BurntSushi5: The type of `INITIAL_VLOG_STARTUP_ROUTINE` seems janky; `vlog_startup_routines` is a pointer to a function pointer, not a function pointer itself. Faking it and then taking it address to start iterating seems like a round-about way to go about things.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson yep, my objdump says the same; I compiled with `clang library.c -c -g -o libc_library.a` FWIW. I don't think that the [`Pointer` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Pointer.html) has any automatic dereferencing, otherwise it would be pretty useless.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: `vlog_startup_routines` is not a pointer to a function pointer, it's an array of function pointers. When you use the name `vlog_startup_routines` in C code, the array lvalue is coerced to a pointer. That doesn't mean that the variable stores a pointer! The expression `&INITIAL_VLOG_STARTUP_ROUTINE` in Rust code yields the same value as the expression `vlog_startup_routines` in C code.

Comment: @FrancisGagné: Ah! I had forgotten about this implicit conversion occurring in C, and of course in Rust it would have to be explicit. Now it makes much more sense.

Comment: @Shepmaster: I think that Francis nailed it; `INITIAL_VLOG_START_ROUTINE` is a misleading name, because it really is an *array* of routines (of unknown size) and you need to make it a pointer to be iterate over it. In Rust, the type really should be `[VlogStartupRoutine; 1]`; it's a bit of a lie, but since the array has at least one element as per its semantics, it seems better than pretending it's directly a pointer to function.